# Clear flexbox column

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox layout which contains the following elements:

Markup:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 10rem;
  background: grey;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

.row-1--last {
  margin-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wrapper">
  <li class="row-1">
    <a>This is row 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="row-1">
    <a>This is row 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="row-1">
    <a>This is row 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="row-1 row-1--last">
    <a>This is row 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="row-2">
    <a>This is row 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="row-2">
    <a>This is row 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to clear or make the last element of row-1 take up the rest of the space in the column so that the list items with the class `row-2` will be shifted to a new line.

I have tried different things like giving the last `row-1` element padding or margin. I also tried to add a pseudo element and make that one take up the rest of the space.

The height of the li elements is not set.

I'm not sure if it can be solved with CSS purely, or I need to look into JS and maybe calculate some heights.

Check out my codepen here: https://codepen.io/fennefoss/pen/PBNMwd

Comment: There is no “clear” in flexbox. You can not just go and take what you know from one particular layout “system”, and apply it 1:1 onto a different one, that is based on a whole different underlying philosophy.

Comment: Might it be possible to use javascript to calculate the height of of all the row-1 elements and subtract that from the total height, and then set that as the height of the last element?

Comment: Might be … but would it would be a _good_ way to go about this to begin with? If those items have _meanings_ that justify this “separated” display - then why are they crammed into a single list to begin with? And if you _want_ a float-like effect - then why use flexbox to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

flex-grow may be able to help you: can you look into [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) link?

An approach could be to wrap the row-1 classed items into a div, which would itself be a flex container. The items within this container (with class row-1-item, for instance) could use the flex-grow property.

You could then put the row-2 items in another div, and ensure that they are on different lines.

Also, if you want to access the last element of a type, the following may help:

```
.row-1:nth-last-of-type(1) {
  /* add your css */
}
```